# Weird ios behaviour when absolute and z-index are involved

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova

I have a menu that should be in the home-page which is like this:

```
<nav class="main-menu"></nav>
```

And the main-menu css is a simple:

```
.main-menu {
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 11;
}
```

When in ios (after cordova compiling),  i dont see the nav at all.
Inside of the nav i have 3 very big buttons, and when i press on the ios screen (where the nav bar is supposed to be but not shown to me), it redirects me to where i want as if the nav is there but i just dont see it, What can be the cause of this weird behaviour?

Comment: post the html code also...

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your `html` / `body` CSS like this?

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

If not, you won't be able to use percentage for height values (relative to the screen size, this is). You can set the height to some pixel value, which will also work.

Although this may be a `z-index` issue. Try setting `z-index` to `9999` and see if it is visible.

Comment: Could you post some more HTML?

Comment: Also, the CSS properties for the inner buttons would help me understand your problem more.

Comment: like i said, it looks like a z-index problem, only that the elements are there! but not showing for some reason, meaning i press the screen where the element should be (but i dont see it) and it do what it suppose to do

Comment: If it would be an z-index issue, it would be fixed by simply setting it to 9999. Have you any other style properties set? Like me, and Banik, pointed out: more code would be helpful to understand the issue.

Comment: But if its a z-index problem, how come the buttons are "presseble"?

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle / URL or could make one?